# Set all categories Use Parent Category Settings to yes

Tags: magento-1.9, database, category, layout

I need to set all categories Use Parent Category Settings to "Yes" from mysql

I have done this sql query:

```
SELECT * FROM eav_attribute where attribute_code = 'custom_use_parent_settings';
```

wich give me attribute_id = 68

if i do

```
UPDATE catalog_category_entity_int set value = 1 where attribute_id = 68;
```

only 103 rows are affected but i have 3000 categories

I am missing someting ?
only level 1 categories are affected by the query

Answer (score 1):

I tested your queries and works for me. I can think only at this scenario.
If `value` is already set to 1 that row is not modified. Run this query first:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM catalog_category_entity_int WHERE attribute_id = 68 AND value = 0;
```

And see how many categories don't use parent category settings and you can run this to see how many already used parent category settings:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM catalog_category_entity_int WHERE attribute_id = 68 AND value = 1;
```

Comment: if i run   SELECT COUNT(*) FROM catalog_category_entity_int WHERE attribute_id = 68 AND value = 0;    i have 0 results

Comment: That means all the categories are set to get parent category settings. So everything is what you want. Right?

Comment: no is not if i run  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM catalog_category_entity_int WHERE attribute_id = 68 AND value = 1;  i get 109  rows.

Comment: And what you get if you run: SELECT * FROM catalog_category_entity_int WHERE attribute_id = 68; ? Or SELECT COUNT(*) FROM catalog_category_entity_int WHERE attribute_id = 68;

Comment: I get count 109

Comment: So, if you can see, the problem is not with the queries. You have only 109 (child) categories I guess. If you say that you have 3000 categories probably they don't have parents, I can't figure what else could be the problem...